# How do I set the height and width for images that use a responsive images style?

Tags: 8, media, performance

When using the core Image module, the height and width of images are automatically set.  But when I use the Responsive Images module and a Responsive Image style, then no height or width is set.

Users don't like this because it makes the website look janky because images can pop into place and change the layout suddenly. Google doesn't like this because it slows down the page.  When testing with Lighthouse, it gives the following recommendation:

> Set an explicit width and height on image elements to reduce layout
> shifts and improve CLS. [Learn more](https://web.dev/optimize-cls/)

There was also [an article in Smashing Magazine this year about setting height and width](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/setting-height-width-images-important-again/).

How can I do this in the Responsive Image module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for this is actually pretty simple.

There are a few important points.

1. For this to work, all of the responsive images in a single responsive image style must have the same aspect ratio. They can have different heights and widths, but the aspect ratio must be the same.
2. You have to set the height and width to be the maximum possible (the height and width of the largest image in the responsive image style).

Assuming your responsive image style has a machine name of **hero**, here's some example code:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_responsive_image() for MYMODULE.
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_responsive_image(&$variables) {
  $style_id = $variables['responsive_image_style_id'];
  if ($style_id === 'hero') {
    // Set the height + width to the aspect ratio for all images.
    // Use the largest possible height + width that may be displayed.
    $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['height'] = 450;
    $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['width'] = 800;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure but it solves the problem in page insight if you indicate a width of 100% and an auto height if you are not sure of the ratio. What do you think ? `$variables['img_element']['#attributes']['height'] = '100%';$variables['img_element']['#attributes']['width'] = 'auto';`